# Liferay 7 Error when trying to get web content inside portlet

Tags: java, liferay-7

i am trying to use JournalArticleServiceUtil class to get web content, but it shows an error and i don't know how to fix it, there's my code

```
long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
    System.out.println("GroupId: " + groupId);
    List<JournalArticle> articleList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> news = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        DDMStructure structure = DDMStructureManagerUtil.getStructure(Long.parseLong("94203"));
        articleList = JournalArticleServiceUtil.getArticlesByStructureId(groupId, structure.getStructureKey(), 0, 10, null);
        for (JournalArticle art: articleList) {
            news.add(art.getContent());
        }

    } catch (SystemException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         log.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

the error says

```
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy466 cannot be cast to com.liferay.journal.service.JournalArticleService
```

i hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to the implementation version of the service class you are using. If you are using gradle, you could give preference to compileOnly rules and make sure you match the kernel version in you server with the one you are using. Some times you do need to declare implementation versions directly on you bnd.bnd.

Something like:

```
Import-Package: com.liferay.journal.model;version="[1.0.0,3.0.0)", com.liferay.journal.service; version="[1.0.0,3.0.0)",*
```

Comment: i'm not using gradle, but i will try the configuration in .bnd file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using **JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil** instead of **JournalArticleServiceUtil**.